# How to handle multiple requests in spring boot filter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, servlet-filters

I am developing a custom log with Spring Boot to get information from all incoming request. My problem is when there are multiple requests at the same time the order in the logs gets messed up and unreadable.

**RequestResponseLogger**

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    CustomHttpRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new CustomHttpRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);

    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    log.info("INFO {} {}", f.format(new Date()), uuid);
    log.info("ID : {}", getCurrentlyDateTime());

    // String method = requestWrapper.getMethod();
    // String uri = requestWrapper.getRequestURI();

    log.info("Request URL: {}", requestWrapper.getRequestURL());
    log.info("Host : {}", requestWrapper.getServerName());

    log.info("Request Body: {}", new String(requestWrapper.getByteArray()));

    CustomHttpResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new CustomHttpResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse);

    filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);


    log.info("Response Status : {}", responseWrapper.getStatus());
    log.info("Response Body : {}", new String(responseWrapper.getBaos().toByteArray()));
}
```

I use jmeter to do the test

[jmeter thread group information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxPXU.png)

**The log results**

> INFO 2022/03/07 08:11:52:459 5a2a6f62-3265-47ac-ad08-83551767fd26
>
> INFO 2022/03/07 08:11:52:459 5682ba19-1766-44d9-89c8-97a5b846ac12
>
> INFO 2022/03/07 08:11:52:459 37f2ee3e-0e8f-4c82-b6da-34c11b8b7aa2
>
> INFO 2022/03/07 08:11:52:459 04392344-2b2d-4efb-a6ea-fe2d8310004f
>
> ID : 20220307081152
>
> ID : 20220307081152
>
> ID : 20220307081152
>
> ID : 20220307081152
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:8080/user/764
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:8080/user/359
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:8080/user/63
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:8080/user/123

**Expected results**

> INFO 2022/03/07 08:11:52:459 5a2a6f62-3265-47ac-ad08-83551767fd26
>
> ID : 20220307081152
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:8080/user/764
>
> INFO 2022/03/07 08:11:52:459 5682ba19-1766-44d9-89c8-97a5b846ac12
>
> ID : 20220307081152
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:8080/user/359
>
> INFO 2022/03/07 08:11:52:459 37f2ee3e-0e8f-4c82-b6da-34c11b8b7aa2
>
> ID : 20220307081152
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:8080/user/63
>
> INFO 2022/03/07 08:11:52:459 04392344-2b2d-4efb-a6ea-fe2d8310004f
>
> ID : 20220307081152
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:8080/user/123

What is best practice to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: Well you don't. Unless you syncronize on something and basically cripple your service. You need to add something to your logs (a trace id) which you can then later use to filter the lines you need.

Comment: Or put multiple items into one log statement.